# GetElementById Two same ID's

Tags: vb.net

Hey I need help well im trying to make a program that uses a site to do some stuff and it has two of the same id's for both textboxs im trying to input into my code is `WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("form-control-3").InnerText = BunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text`. Well anyway im tryint to do that to input into the first textbox and the 2nd textbox has the same id and classname so i don't really know what to do.

Comment: Do you have any influence over the site that is serving faulty HTML?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate `id` values in an HTML document, that's not valid HTML All `id` values _must be unique_ within a HTML document.  If you need to select multiple elements, use a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try grabbing all the HTML elements based on the tag and then loop through to see if the id matched. Something like...

```
Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection
Elems = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("[tagName]")
For Each elem as HtmlElement in Elems
     Dim idStr As String = elem.GetAttribute("id")
     If ((idStr IsNot Nothing) And (idStr = "form-control-3"))
          elem.InnerText = BunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text
     End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this help but you can do a input array
example:

```
<input name="name[]">
```

and...

```
document.getElementsByName("name[]")
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to use `name` instead of `id`, which should be unique across a page

Comment: Yes, I forgot that, sorry